# Compute within sum of squares from PAM cluster analysis in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pam

I am working on a cluster analysis with PAM in R. I computed the gower distance for my data with vegdist() and computing a cluster variable with pam() works well. Now I need a measure to determine the right k. The method I know is to visually compare the within sum of squares for different ks. How can I fetch the WSS from a series of PAM iterations to compare the sums in a plot, analogously to this example for kmeans? http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/137758_a80b40255fdd440ab76b41a646a6c482.html#loops

Comment: WSS is the objective function of k-means, but you are not using k-means. Why not use the PAM objective function?

Comment: What would be the right way to do that?

Comment: See `?pam.object` for the `objective` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAM does not optimize WSS. WSS is the k-means objective.

Instead, use the PAM objective (maybe called TD in literature?)

See `?[pam.object][1]` for the `objective` field:

> `objective`
>
> > the objective function after the first and second step of the pam algorithm.

Beware that similar to WSS, `objective` is supposed to decrease with increasing k. Thus you can't just choose the minimum, but you should look for a knee in the plot.

Because PAM is randomized, you may want to run each k multiple times, and keep the best result only.

Comment: Thanks, the connection between the theoretical background of PAM and the structure of the R function was the missing link here!